# Why did Doctor Fate sacrifice himself to Sabbac?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, character-motivation, black-adam-2022

In the *Black Adam* (2022) movie, Doctor Fate first surrounded the castle with a force field, fought Sabbac, and in the middle of the fight freed Black Adam from the prison.

If Doctor Fate had the power to awaken and free Black Adam remotely, why didn’t he do it in the beginning instead of getting himself killed?

Comment: Cuz the script said so.